# Address booking and writing to file

Tags: c, file-io

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct contact {    
char firstname [40];    
char lastname [40]; 
char address [100]; 
char phone[10];
}contact;   


int main ()
{   FILE *pFile;
    contact entry = {""};
    int choice, firstname_flag = TRUE, lastname_flag = TRUE, address_flag = TRUE, phone_flag = TRUE;

    pFile = fopen("C:\\contacts.txt", "a+");

    if(!pFile){
        printf("File could not be open.");
        return 1;
        }

    do{
    printf("Choose a selection:\n\n");
    printf("1. First name:\n");
    printf("2. Last name:\n");
    printf("3. Address:\n");
    printf("4. Phone number:\n\n");
    scanf( "%d", &choice);
    }while((choice < 1 || choice > 4));

    switch (choice){
    case 1:
        firstname_flag = FALSE;
        printf("Please enter first name: \n");    
        scanf("%s", &entry.firstname);
        break;
    case 2:
        lastname_flag = FALSE;
        printf("Please enter last name: \n");     
        scanf("%s", &entry.lastname);
        break;
    case 3:
        address_flag = FALSE;
        printf("Please enter address: \n");   
        scanf("%s", &entry.address);
        break;
    case 4:
        phone_flag = FALSE;
        printf("Please enter phone number: \n");      
        scanf("%s", &entry.phone);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    printf("\nYou will now be asked to enter the other items. \n\n");

    if(firstname_flag){
        printf("Please enter first name: \n");
        scanf("%s", &entry.firstname);
    }    
    if(lastname_flag){
    printf("Please enter last name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &entry.lastname);
    }
    if(address_flag){
        printf("Please enter address: \n");
        scanf("%s", &entry.address);
    }
    if(phone_flag){
        printf("Please enter phone number: \n");
        scanf("%s", &entry.phone);
    }

    fwrite (here)

    fclose(pFile);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code I have so far. First of all is there anything blatant that pokes out as being invalid or wrong practice etc? 2nd I want to write first name,last name,address, and Phone # to a file. I'm unsure if I need to fwrite "entry" or not. Also, I have noticed when selecting Address first that It's almost like the buffer isn't empty and what I put after the space i.e. 123 Park , Park would be used as the first name wrongly and the next entry I would put in would be Last name. Any suggestions on the code usage and anything at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: Two quick observations. `main` is too long, split it into separate functions. Indentation is inconsistent. Take a look and [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and observe what does it do with your code.

Comment: most of the indentation problems may be because I was trying to make it looks reasonable on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

N° 1. In response to: “invalid or wrong practice.” Some of these are more matters of taste…

- If you ‘must’ use `scanf`, don't point it at a string buffer with `%s`: specify the length of the buffer with something like `%32s` to *reduce* (but perhaps not eliminate) someone from just typing too much and crashing your program (or worse…) — But, Read N°3 below for more on this question…

  - If you're developing something open-source, or for personal use, GNU `readline` is a very nice option (but it is *GPL* not *LGPL*, so it can't be used in "non-libre" works…)
- Your structure initializer doesn't cover all the elements. You could use `{"", "", "", ""}`
- Did you mean `fwrite(entry)`?
- If you're checking for missing fields before writing the file, you might want to leave aside the bank of flags, and instead loop on the "invalid condition."

  ```
   while ('\0' == entry.firstname[0]) {
      printf("Please enter first name: \n");
      scanf("%40[^\r\n\0\04]", &entry.firstname[0]);
   }
  ```
- No need to open the file so early, and leave it open while waiting for user interaction. Opening the file in `a+` mode is reasonably "dangerous" (see `man lockf` for the skinny), because someone else might try to write to the file while you are; leaving it open in this mode for a long time increases the risk.
- You should probably use `strerror(errno)` to provide the user the details of a failing system call, such as when checking the return codes of `fopen`, `fwrite`, and `fclose`. Due to the way buffered I/O works, `fclose` could even be reporting a problem that occurred with `fwrite` under some circumstances.
- Print your error messages to `stderr` using `fprintf (stderr,`…`);` instead of the output stream …
- If you *are* going to use flags to indicate that the data is "valid" (or, at least, that it may be), you should probably do so *after* the user tries to enter it, instead of before.
- Functions are your friends … I would probably break up something like this by using a function to collect the user's input (something like `prompt_for_field ("first name", &entry.firstname);`), a function to check for missing records and prompt for them, and a function to write the record to the file, at least …
- It's usually considered good form to `exit` from `main`, rather than `return`, for example by using `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`/`exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. I believe the idea is to support esoteric and possible extinct systems who might treat some value(s) other than `0` as a successful status code (VMS, perhaps?), but regardless, it's easier to read :-)

## 2

And N°2, yes, you can `fwrite(entry)`, and as long as you never change the definition of `struct contact`, you should be able to read it back in all right. Over time, you'll probably want to switch to a more "plain text" type format (`#include <json-xml-init-religious-war>`), but in this small example, there isn't a pressing need to introduce such complexity.

## 3

Finally, N°3, you should probably use `&entry.address[0]` to get the address of the start of a `char[]` but most significantly: **`scanf %s` does not read a string.** It *looks* like `printf %s`, but it's not…

> s      Matches  a  sequence  of non-white-space characters; the next
>   pointer must be a pointer to character
>                 array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and  the  terminating  null  character  ('\0'),
>                 which  is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width,
>                 whichever occurs first.

See that "non-white-space?" That's what's got you. The rest of your input (after the first whitespace) is left in the keyboard buffer, waiting for another `scanf` to read it. A good('ish) way to read from the terminal and accept whitespace is `%40[^\r\n\0\04]`, replacing *40* with the size of your string buffer (`char[]`). That means, accept (up to) 40 characters, as long as they are none of: carriage return, new line, the null byte, or end-of-file code (`^D`).

All-in-all, you look to be on the right track, though. Good luck :-)